# What makes something chametz?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven

Can I a recipe that uses **flour** *but not* **water**?

As kids, we all learned that if the water and the flour touch for more than 18 minutes, then the matzo is chametz.

When 20 ingredients are combined, none of which are water or yeast, can the resulting food be kosher for Passover?

Comment: Are there other liquids involved? Fruit Juice? Oil?

Comment: Note that (AFAIK but of course CYLOR) most flour on the market is presumed (or known?) to be _chametz_ and cannot be used on _Pesach_. This question then is only about flour that's not yet _chametz_.

Comment: Part of the bleaching process for flour is that they soak the grain in water for more than 18 minutes.

Comment: One can purchase unbleached flour in regular stores (at least in the US).

Comment: @DoubleAA: I substitute margarine for butter, other than that, the only real liquid is vanilla extract.

Comment: Must the unbleached flower that I buy be certified as kosher for Passover, (not just kosher/parave)?

Comment: @wizlog that last comment of yours can be generalized to anything: must you buy cheese/milk/wine/meat/olive oil/a million other products only if its certified kosher for passover?

Comment: @wizlog Vanilla extract is usually ~50% water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it might depend whether you're an Ashkenazi or not.

In principle, as you say, flour (that never became wet, as in the comments to the question) mixed with liquids other than water can't become chametz, and therefore Shulchan Aruch ([Orach Chaim 462:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=127)) permits eating baked goods made in this way on Pesach.

However, Rema ([ibid. :4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=128)) states that "in these countries it is not customary to knead using juice" (as Mishnah Berurah :15 says, this is in deference to the opinions that flour with juice can indeed become chametz, plus the concern that some water may have been mixed into the liquid, which is universally agreed to make it become chametz faster than plain water), "and this [custom] should not be altered except in case of great need, such as for a sick or old person who needs it." (Mishnah Berurah :18 adds that even after the fact - if a dough was made using juice in violation of this custom, and not for the sake of an old or sick person - it should not be eaten on Pesach, although it can be saved for after the holiday.)

Comment: Per comments on the question, the asker uses vanilla extract, which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_extract) says "is made by macerating and percolating vanilla beans in a solution of ethyl alcohol and water".

Answer (score -1):

There are two "modes" you can take upon yourself answering this question.
First mode - the written law
Second mode - the rabbinical Halacha for chametz

The torah states:

> כָּל מַחְמֶצֶת לֹא תֹאכֵלוּ בְּכֹל מוֹשְׁבֹתֵיכֶם תֹּאכְלוּ מַצּוֹת.

[Biological Leavening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leavening#Biological_leaveners)  (MACHMEZET) requires flour, water, and time. The Israelites did not have time. Technically speaking if you use flour with any liquid and immediately put it in the  oven, you won't have CHAMETZ.

The Halacha, if I understand correctly (am not an expert) also applies "water, time" over grains themselves, not only flour. Which means that any grain that got rain, is suspected in being Chametz.